ValueError: Unknown layer: 'TFOpLambda'
When i try to save my model as hdf5,then I get This following error
ValueError: Unknown layer: 'TFOpLambda'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.

Here is my code

def predict(image):
    # Load the model using custom object scope
    with tf.keras.utils.custom_object_scope(custom_object_scope()):
        loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

    img_array = np.array(image)
    img = tf.image.resize(img_array, size=(256, 256))
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = img / 255.
    intensity = loaded_model.predict(img)
    return intensity

I'm using
TensorFlow version: 2.16.1
Keras version: 3.3.3

